# Exception Occurs While Opening a Downloaded Excel Sheet(.xls) In Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net

I download an Excel Sheet by using the following code.
[image]

The above code is starting code of my logic.After downloaded, I open the Excel Sheet.It shows an Warning like this

[image]

Because of this warning,when Im trying to upload the same page to Mysql DataBase using Asp.Net.It shows an Exception like "Page is not in correct Format".

This Is My Entire Logic For Downloading an Excel Sheet

```
protected void download_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

    ExportToExcel(SqlDataSource1, "StudentMarks");
  }
public void ExportToExcel(SqlDataSource dataSrc, string fileName)
{
    //Add Response header 
    Response.Clear();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename={0}.xls", fileName));
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
    //GET Data From Database                
    MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(dataSrc.ConnectionString);
    // string query =  dataSrc.SelectCommand.Replace("\r\n", " ").Replace("\t", " ");
    MySqlCommand cmd9 = new MySqlCommand("select subject from class_subject where standard='" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value + "';", cn);
    // cn.Open();

    //DataSet ds9=new DataSet();
    MySqlDataAdapter da9 = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd9);
    // da9.Fill(ds9);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da9.Fill(dt);

    StringBuilder sb9 = new StringBuilder();




    for (int count = 0; count < dt.Rows.Count; count++)
    {
        // string headerRowText = GridView4.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Text;
        sb9.Append("'");
        sb9.Append(dt.Rows[count][0].ToString());
        sb9.Append("'");
        if (count < dt.Rows.Count - 1)
        //if (count < count3 - 1)
        {
            sb9.Append(",");
        }
    }
    Label2.Text = sb9.ToString();
    //MySqlCommand fyearcmd = new MySqlCommand("select fyear from student_data where standard='" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value + "' and completed_status='running';", cn);
    //MySqlDataReader fyeardr = fyearcmd.ExecuteReader();

    string query = "select Admission_Num,Name,'Standard','Fyear','Type_of_exam'," + sb9.ToString() + " from student_data where standard='" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value + "' and fyear='" + DropDownList4.SelectedItem.Value + "';";

    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, cn);

    cmd.CommandTimeout = 999999;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    try
    {
        cn.Open();
        MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        //Session["fieldcount"] = dr.FieldCount.ToString();
        //Label1.Text = dr.FieldCount.ToString();
        //Add Header  
        int count3 = 4;
        for (int count = 0; count < dr.FieldCount; count++)
        //for (int count = 0; count < count3; count++)
        {
            if (dr.GetName(count) != null)
                sb.Append(dr.GetName(count));
            if (count < dr.FieldCount - 1)
            //if (count < count3 - 1)
            {
                sb.Append("\t");
            }
        }
        Response.Write(sb.ToString() + "\n");
        Response.Flush();
        //Append Data
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            sb = new StringBuilder();

            //for (int col = 0; col < dr.FieldCount - 1; col++)
            for (int col = 0; col <= count3; col++)
            {
                if (col < (count3 - 2))
                {

                    if (!dr.IsDBNull(col))
                        sb.Append(dr.GetValue(col).ToString().Replace(",", " "));
                    sb.Append("\t");
                }
                if (col == (count3 - 2))
                {

                    if (!dr.IsDBNull(col))
                        sb.Append(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text);
                    sb.Append("\t");
                }
                if (col == (count3 - 1))
                {
                    if (!dr.IsDBNull(col))
                    {
                        //sb.Append(dr.GetValue(col).ToString().Replace(",", " "));
                        sb.Append(DropDownList4.SelectedItem.Text);
                    }
                    sb.Append("\t");
                }
                if (col == count3)
                {
                    if (!dr.IsDBNull(col))
                    {
                        //sb.Append(dr.GetValue(col).ToString().Replace(",", " "));
                        sb.Append(DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Text);
                    }
                    sb.Append("\t");
                }
            }
            //if (!dr.IsDBNull(dr.FieldCount - 1))
            //    sb.Append(dr.GetValue(dr.FieldCount - 1).ToString().Replace(",", " "));
            Response.Write(sb.ToString() + "\n");
            Response.Flush();

        }
        dr.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        cmd.Connection.Close();
        cn.Close();
    }
    Response.End();
}
```

So Please give me the suggestion how to download the Excel Sheet with out showing errors while opening.

Comment: How do you create the xls?

Comment: Please Check the Question Once again.I changed Now.

Comment: That's not an error, it's a warning only and it happens every time you create a file with the xls extension and in reality contains the XML format supported by Excel (I forgot the exact name of this format) or any other format for that mattter. You can disable this warning from the registry if it bothers you, or you can set the file extension to .XML and have excel open the file. Whatever option you chose, is not ideal. I'd leave that alone and explain to the user that he should click "yes" when the warning pops up.

Answer (score 1):

You you are generating a csv file, not a excel file. Try to change you header:

```
Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=myfilename.csv");
```

Normally excel is default for opening csv files.